# Reading a file in C with File Descriptor

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

I want to read from a file by using its file descriptor. I can't use its name because of assignment rules.

I obtain it by calling `open` and it works fine.  At this moment I know that I have to use the `read()` function in order to read from it. My problem is that `read()` function requires as an argument the *number of bytes* to read, and I want to read a whole line from the file each time, so I don't know how many bytes to read.

If i use for example `fscanf()`, it works fine with a simple string and I take back the whole line as I want. So my question is:

Is there any function like `fscanf()` which can be called with file descriptor and not with a file pointer?

Comment: Well, you could buffer the incoming characters, and once you have enough (could be a space, or a \n) you can run sscanf on the resulting buffer. Beware that the buffer will not be NUL-terminated; you'll have to add the NUL yourself.

Comment: Why aren't you using stdio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "have to use `read()`" I can't tell if that's your understanding of the situation given a file descriptor from `open()` or a restriction on some kind of assignment.

If you have a file descriptor but you're more comfortable with `fscanf()` and friends, use `fdopen()` to get a `FILE *` from your fd and proceed to use stdio.

Internally it uses functions like `read()` into a buffer and then processes those buffers as you read them with `fscanf()` and friends.

Comment: It was my wrong understanding of the situtation.The only restriction is that i have to use the file descriptor,not just call fopen() with file's name (and this because it is a shared function in which i don't have the name of the file and i only pass its file descriptor as an argument from the main file and then i have to work with it ;)).I didn't know that i can obtain a file pointer with fdopen()...Thought that the only way to read from it was by using read()...Thanks for your help..:)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is read one character at a time, until you've read the entire line, and detect a '/n'. As this is homework, I won't write it for you.

A few things to be warned of, however.

1. You need to check for EOF, otherwise, you might end up in an infinite loop.
2. You should declare some buffer which you read a character, then copy it into the buffer. Not knowing what your input is, I can't suggest a size, other than to say that for a homework assignment, [256] would probably be sufficient.
3. You need to make sure you don't overfill your buffer in the even that you do run over it's length.
4. Keep reading until you find a '/n' character. Then process the line that you have created, and start the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I was thinking of something like that,but if i can obtain the file pointer and use fscanf it is easier for me.